# session_start(): Write of lock failed

Tags: php, memcached

i'm using memcached in php to handle sessions.

But i'm geting a `session_start(): Write of lock failed`.

my php configuration has

```
session.save_handler    memcached  
session.save_path   tcp://127.0.0.1:11211
```

my memcached server is running and i can telnet `127.0.0.1 11211` with success

What does this mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like session.save_path shouldn't contain 'tcp://'.

"memcached" don't need 'tcp' but "memcache" needs.

thanks for you time,

Comment: I had a similar issue where I was migrating to laravel framework, which only supports the php-pecl-memcached driver, while my legacy software was using php-pecl-memcache as well as the session.save_handler. Anyway between switching around both of these things I ended up with the same error, so I did as you said, removing the "tcp://" and that worked for me. So thanks. I would accept your answer if I was the OP.

Comment: You should accept your own answer. This is the correct answer.

Comment: Boy you saved my day!